# Date register sorting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I've created a program that works as a birthday register where you input a date (Name, Date) in to an ArrayList and I can then print them out in a dialog window. I would however like to sort them by Date number and then print that out. Ive tried this, but Ive gotten stuck and would appreciate some support.

This is the code I've written so far, which doesn't work. I found the algorithm online as psuedo-code.

```
public String sortDate(){ // 

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            boolean[]help = new boolean[reg.size()];

            for(int i = 0; i<reg.size()-1;i++){
                    int min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    int minIndex = -1;
                    for(int k = i; k<reg.size()-1; k++){
                            if(help[k]=false && Integer.parseInt(reg.get(k).getDate())< min){
                                    minIndex = k;
                                    min = reg.get(k).getDateInt();

                            }


                    }

                    sb.append(reg.get(minIndex).getDate()+"\n");
                    help[minIndex] = true;
            }
            return sb.toString();
}
```

I end up getting the wrong output. I get the value of the first date in the array times the size of my array. Lets say, if I have 3 dates in my array and the first value is (890105) then the output gives me:

```
890105
890105
890105
```

The psuedo code I found is:

```
create something that stores the search result (ex. StringBuilder object)
create a boolean array (where all elements are false by start)
for i = 0 to size-1:
    m = big value
    for k = 0 to size-1:
        if help[k] is false and the value on spot k < min:
            index = k;
            m = value on spot k;
add m at the end of the search result
help[index] = true;
```

Thankful for any help I can get

Comment: Hint: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`. You are doing `reg.get(min)`, and in the beginning you are initializing `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Can you see that you are sometimes doing `reg.get(min)` while `min` has this value?

Comment: What is `reg`? Use `Collestion.sort(List)` or `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`.

Comment: reg (register) is the ArrayList where all the Name and Dates are stored. I would also like to try writing the algorithm myself for educational purposes, hence not using Collection sort

Comment: Probably issue is here: sb.append(reg.get(min).getDate()+"\n");, and should be: sb.append(reg.get(minIndex).getDate()+"\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bug:

```
if(help[k]=false && ...
```

You are **assigning** the value `false` to `help[k]` here, and the whole expression in the `if (...)` evaluates to `false`. So, the body of the `if` is not executed, `min` stays at `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then you do `reg.get(min)`, leading to the exception that you see.

Did you mean:

```
// Note: == instead of =
if (help[k] == false && ...
```

or better:

```
if (!help[k] && ...
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

```
//first:
int min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
//later...
reg.get(min)
```

do you see a problem here?

Comment: But it also puts min as reg.get(k).getDateInt() within the for/if loop

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it should be:

```
sb.append(reg.get(minIndex).getDate()+"\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, it resolved the compilation error. However, I get the wrong output. I get the value of the first date in the array times the size of my array. Lets say, if I have 3 dates in my array and the first value is (890105) then the output gives me: 890105, 890105, 890105